# Is there a way to position InnerHTML so it comes under something within the normal html

Tags: css, innerhtml

I have a question regarding innerHTML positioning. I have a form which also has a timer countdown being displayed using innerHTML. The thing is it is currently above my form which ends up causing some issues which I am not going to explain and I would like to place it under the form. I know I can declare how far is is from the bottom, the top, left, right, etc of the page however I do not with to do this as this would require an absolute position whereas I do not want it to be absolute but still sit under my form. Here is the code containing it placed on top currently:

```
<div id="checking"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(5,"checking");</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
<div id=main>
<br><br>
<form method="POST" id="quizzes" action="">
     <label for="question"><?php echo ($currentQuestion+1).". ".  $questionsAndAnwsers[$currentQuestion]["question"];
    ?></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="currentQuestion" value="<?php echo   $currentQuestion;?>"><br>
    <input type="text" name="guess" value="" placeholder="Answer...">
    <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Next Question">
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
seconds = 15;
runningtime = setInterval(function () {
    var element = document.getElementById("checking");
    element.innerHTML = "<h2 style='text-align:center'>   <b>"+seconds+"</b> seconds</h2>";
    if(seconds < 1){
        clearInterval(runningtime);
        document.getElementById('quizzes').submit();
    }
    seconds--;
}, 1000)
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `innerHTML` of a `<div>`, it puts the content **in that div**.

If you don't want it at the top of your document, *don't put that `<div>` at the top of your document*.

Move the `<div>` in the source code.